# Поиск по каждому элемент списка(ul li)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Привет. Как найти, есть ли в списке определённый текст? Список такой - ul>li>a.
Чтобы в будущем через if сравнить, совпадает ли текст внутри одного из тега а с переменной?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вам нужно текстовое содержимое тега, для этого нужно воспользоваться методом text()

```
селектор.text();
```

Вот небольшой скрипт который ищет текст "need" в списке и выводит результат в консоль через 1с:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  var ArrayElem = $("ul li a");
  for (var i = 0; i<ArrayElem.length; i++) {
    if ($(ArrayElem[i]).text()==="need") {
      console.log("Текст найден в " + $(ArrayElem[i]).attr("class"));
      }
  }
},1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a class="one">some</a></li>
  <li><a class="two">need</a></li>
  <li><a class="three">text</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: в jquery это можно сделать проще: `$("ul li a:contains('need')")`